# How to update status to 1 in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

When I enter the correct text and click the Apply button, the status in the coupons table should change to 1. But it is still 0.

```
public function coupon(Order $order, Request $request)
{
    $coupon = Coupon::where('code', $request->code)->first();
    if (!$coupon) {
        alert()->error('The discount code is incorrect.', 'Warning')->persistent('OK');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
    if ($coupon) {
        $data = [
            'status' => 1
        ];
        $order->update($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to change `'status' => 1` to `'status' => '1'`  integer to string

Comment: Include your coupon migration and model files too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`fill`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment) method to update the $order.

```
$data = [
    'status' => 1
];
$order->fill($data);
$order->save();
```

or you can set the `status` property on the `$order` and save it like this:

```
$order->status = 1;
$order->save();
```

Comment: I get this error, https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1Kud.png , AND I want to only update.

Comment: You either modify the migration for the order and set the `price` as nullable or you also set the price when you update the status. I would update the migration and set the price nullable. Make sure to re-run the migrations after you update the price table field, also make sure you don't do it in production.

Comment: @irankhostravi This error has nothing to do with the function in question! The error is about `orders` table but you are working on `Coupon`!

Comment: Please look this https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EFF0.png

Answer (score 0):

put this in the order model

```php
protected $fillable = ['status'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be this way, you are updating the order model instead of the coupon model

```php
  if ($coupon) {
        $coupon->update(['status' => 1]);
    }
```

Comment: But it is still 0.